# Using an external manifest to turn off Windows DPI scaling

Tags: windows, manifest, dpi

I have a Java application on Windows that's launched through a [packr](https://github.com/libgdx/packr) exe. I need to turn off DPI scaling by default. I don't have control of the exe's generation.

My understanding is that I can do this by adding an external .manifest file, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the manifest file, which I put at "Airships.exe.manifest" next to "Airships.exe".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="Airships.exe"/>
  <asmv3:application xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <asmv3:windowsSettings
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

- Is there something incorrect about this manifest?
- Does an external manifest actually work by default, or do I have to embed it into the .exe somehow?

NB [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242748/how-to-use-manifest-to-control-disable-dpi-scaling-and-compatibility) doesn't actually have an answer.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/packr/blob/master/src/main/native/packr/src/win32/packr_win32.manifest

Comment: Huh. So why do some people end up having to manually set this? Is there some way I can check the manifest of the created exe?

Comment: No real idea why you'd think so, maybe you just saw a bunch of old google hits.  It has been important to embed a manifest for 12 years already.  You don't have to check it, you already know what it looks like from the github link.  Otherwise easy to do with a resource editor/viewer, like Visual Studio.  I don't know what packr does, but it sounds like it just gets this wrong and needs to leave it up to config to do this dynamically.  Consider submitting a bug report.  Or just build your own flavor of it, with an edited manifest.