# Tiny icons in Navigator tab in CF Builder 2018

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusionbuilder

I've just started using ColdFusion Builder 2018 and the icons in the Navigator tab are so small I can't see them:

[image: Navigator Tab]

I've dug around in the settings, but I can't find a way to make these bigger.  I'd expect them to look more like they have in the past and how they currently look on the File View tab:

[image: File View Tab]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This my number one pet peeve with Eclipse and everything built on it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718093/eclipse-interface-icons-very-small-on-high-resolution-screen-in-windows-8-1 for some help

Comment: I've had other apps (haven't used CF Builder 2018, just CF Builder 3) that have a hard time with DPI scaling. If that's the case with this application, I've had success with creating an external manifest file to turn off DPI scaling (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188256/using-an-external-manifest-to-turn-off-windows-dpi-scaling).

Comment: You can try the solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473037/very-small-fonts-and-icons-on-4k-screens/48473038#48473038